# As3 - Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, null

i have been trying to solve this for days and i just cant get whats worng, im simply added  hitTest between my "Character" to a "candy". at the begining its working, then i get an error #1009 Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at "Candy" line 49

the "Candy" Class

```
public class Candy extends MovieClip
{
    public var leadingMover:Mover;
    public var mainColliderCandy:Character;
    public var hit:MovieClip;
    public var hitParent:*;
    public var candy:MovieClip;


    public function Candy()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, allLoaded);
    }

    private function allLoaded(event:Event):void
    {
            hitParent = event.currentTarget.parent;
            candy = MovieClip(this.parent.getChildByName(this.name));
            hit = hitCandy_mc;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    }

    private function update(event:Event):void
    {
        if(leadingMover)
        {
            y +=leadingMover.speed;
        }
        else
        {
            leadingMover = Mover(parent.getChildByName("bg_mc"));
        }

        if(mainColliderCandy && candy)
        {
            if(hit.hitTestObject(mainColliderCandy))
            {

            //mainColliderCandy.collidedWithCandy(this);

                if(candy)
                {
                    //mainColliderCandy = null;
                    this.parent.removeChild(candy);
                }   
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mainColliderCandy = Character(parent.getChildByName("character_mc"));
        }
    }

}
```

}

thank you!

Comment: Can you please tell us, what is line 49 in your code? And what is `hitCandy_mc`?

Comment: sorry line 49 is :       this.parent.removeChild(candy); ... hitCandy_mc is a movieClip inside the main movieClip. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your error is at line

```
this.parent.removeChild(candy);
```

`this.parent` is `null`. I think you should add

```
candy.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
```

inside the curly braces, at line 50. I don't really understand what your code is supposed to do, but it may be what you wanted to do at line

```
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
```

but it removes the listener on `this` instead of the removed candy.